# How to fix this bug in the Kotlin Web Demo?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a real n00b in Kotlin and have just started with its [demo](http://kotlin-demo.jetbrains.com/?folder=Problems&name=Runs).

The problem solution is trivial, but there's a bug in

```
private fun assertEquals<T>(actual : T?, expected : T?, message : Any? = null) {
    if (actual != expected) {
        errors++
        println("Test failed")
        val trace = Thread.currentThread()?.getStackTrace()!!
        if (trace.size > 6) {
            // Finding relevant stack frames
            val location = trace.getFrameAfter("runs.Tester", "expect") // ERROR HERE
            val function = trace.getFrameAfter("runs.TesterRunner", "forFunction") // AND HERE
            println("at ${function?.getClassName()}.${function?.getMethodName()}(line:${location?.getLineNumber()})")
        }
        if (message != null)
            println(message)
    }
    else if (!skipSuccessful)
        println("OK")
}
```

which I don't understand. It says

```
 Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.Array<java.lang.StackTraceElement> but
 kotlin.Array<java.lang.StackTraceElement?> was expected
```

and I can neither how the former was inferred nor why the latter is expected. Especially I don't understand where can two such assumption come from a single method call.

I "fixed" it by removing the offending lines, but I'm sure someone can enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that function `getFrameAfter` is defined on `kotlin.Array<java.lang.StackTraceElement?>`, but you tried to call it on variable `trace`, that was of type `kotlin.Array<java.lang.StackTraceElement>`.

We've fixed the example on Kotlin Web Demo, so you can try it again.

Comment: I've changes your *italics* ( * ) to `code quote` ( ` ) for better readability.

Comment: I completely missed the declaration of `trace`, this makes it clear. Thanks.